# What counts as "using only missiles" for the second Rock Cruiser achievement?

Tags: achievements, ftl-faster-than-light

I am trying to get the second achievement for the rock cruiser "Destroy an enemy ship with a defense drone using only missiles."  Can I get this achievement if I also use an Ion weapon?

The text indicates that the enemy must be destroyed.  To destroy a ship you must do damage ether with weapons (missiles, bombs, beams, lasers) or with fire.  The "with" of the statement could be referring to the use of any of these to do damage to the enemy ship.

The achievement could also have other constraints, like not being able to beam crew over and attack systems, not use cloak or shields  or engines, etc.  To me it sounds like you may only damage the hull with missile weapons.  If this is the case then I could send my crew over to the enemy ship, take out their Drone Control system and rain down missiles as I please.  I could also use ion weapons.

I would prefer the answer provide some proof backing up the claim.

Comment: I think you're trying to get around the requirements of the achievement; it says "using only missiles".  As for ion weapons, since they don't do damage, they should be fine.  Might be an easy way to disable the defense drone.

Comment: May I propose changing the title to _"What counts as a weapon for the second Rock Cruiser achievement?"_

Comment: @IQAndreas The question is really more about what resources I can use to interact with the enemy ship the what is a weapon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a teleporter to send crewmen, remember as they damage a system the enemy ship loses 1hp in hull damage as well (ruining your chance for the achievement get). Same goes for systems damaged by fire spread.

Your best bet is to get 2-3 weapons that fire missiles, and don't auto-fire them. When they are all fully charged, pause, and target drone system and weapons. The drone might be able to destroy one missile, but the others should hopefully hit.

Comment: @Trisped - Ion weapons don't 'damage' systems, I'm not 100% sure, but the achievement logic may simply check whether you've used a non-missile weapon. If I were programming it, it would be a lot simpler to check whether each weapon fired was missle based - so if there's a missle-based ion weapon, that might work.

Comment: Yeah, if I was programming it I would have made a more accurate description.  I went ahead and marked your answer as correct since you answered most of the current question and I do not want to come back in 3 months to see if anyone managed to find out for sure on the ion weapon thing.  Maybe I will try to ask the developers.

Answer (score 5):

The [FTL wiki page](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Defense_Drones_Don%27t_Do_D%27anything!) on this achievement lays out specific conditions for the achievement.  Ion weapons for instance are explicitly not allowed, according to the wiki.